# Select a first word of string variable and the first time it occurs

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to apply a row selection, but it need to be done using the first word of a string variable. So I can select the first occurrence of that row.

I tried like this: `(substr(aux$AIO[1], start =1, stop = 7)=="Neutral")`

But it is selecting just the all the occurrences for the first subject of the dataset instead the first for all subjects.

This is basically how the data and the idea works:

```
ID  Attempt Type           Time
1   1       Neutral lotion 10
1   1       Acid lotion    15 
1   2       Neutral lotion  8
1   2       Sweet lotion   17
2   1       Neutral lotion 11
2   1       Acid lotion    13
2   2       Neutral lotion  9
2   2       Sweet lotion   15
```

I need to select for each ID and for each trial per ID the first occurrence of the neutral condition so I can subtract the time expend in the acid and sweet condition against the neutral condition.

Comment: It is great you have added some code, but if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question it's much more likely we can pick it up and show you a  possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started.

```
test <- c('This is a test.', 'Neutral Density', 'Cool cucumber.')

library(stringr)

ans <- str_match(test, '^\\w+\\b')
ans
#     [,1]     
#[1,] "This"   
#[2,] "Neutral"
#[3,] "Cool"

which(ans[,1] == 'Neutral')
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame('ID' = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 'Attempt' = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), 
                 'Type' = c('Neutral lotion', 'Acid lotion', 'Neutral lotion', 
                          'Sweet lotion', 'Neutral lotion', 'Acid lotion',
                          'Neutral lotion', 'Sweet lotion'),
                 'Time' = c(10, 15, 8, 17, 11, 13, 9, 15), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Attempt) %>%
  slice(which(Type == 'Neutral lotion')[1])
```

Which yields

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID, Attempt [4]
     ID Attempt           Type  Time
  <dbl>   <dbl>          <chr> <dbl>
1     1       1 Neutral lotion    10
2     1       2 Neutral lotion     8
3     2       1 Neutral lotion    11
4     2       2 Neutral lotion     9
```